# Did the Vilna Gaon ever mention the Ramchal by name in his writings?

Tags: ramchal, vilna-gaon

It is said that the Vilna Gaon thought very highly of the Ramchal. I would like to know if he is ever mentioned by name by the Gra?

Comment: I quote I have heard in the gra's name is he said the ramchal had a perfect understanding of the entire Torah

Comment: heard a shiur of rabbi yaakov hillel that everything the ramchal says is from sources in the arizal zohar and others, so perhaps the gra would go for the earlier source